# Spring boot security http basic con oauth2 resource server

Tags: spring, http, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth2

Estoy intentando configurar una aplicacion spring boot web para utilizar la seguridad de http basica la cual será utilizada para las paginas web, y adicional necesito implementar la seguridad OAuth2 para que una aplicacion android se conecte.

El problema que tengo es que la seguridad OAuth está sobre-escribiendo la seguridad http basica. Buscando en google encontré que se debe al orden de ejecucion de los filtros de seguridad por lo que había que anotar el ResourceServer con @Order(3) y el WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter con @Order(1) para que de esta forma se aplicara primero la seguridad basica. Sin embargo me encuentro con que el http basico inicia sesión bien, pero cuando intenta autenticar los roles del usuario, no los toma. El servidor de Autorizacion OAuth si funciona y genera el token, pero cuando intenta acceder a los recursos protegidos, tampoco toma los roles asignados al usuario o simplemente no protege los recursos. En cambio cuando desactivo una de las dos seguridades (http basica o la seguridad OAuth) si funciona la autenticacion de los roles correctamente y protege las rutas indicadas.

Es como si al mezclar ambos sistemas, uno sobreescribiera al otro.

Cual sería la forma correcta en que pueda integrar ambas funciones (http basica y OAuth) en una misma aplicacion spring boot? Leí algo sobre los http.antMatchers pero no logro entenderlo.

**WebSecurityConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(1)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        log.info("Configurando http security web");

        http.httpBasic();

        // Indica los recursos a proteger
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/home", "/about").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/cuenta/**").access("hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')");

        // Administra la sesion
        /*http.sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html")
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);*/

        // Configura el login
        http.formLogin()
                .successHandler(savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login_check")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password");

        // Configura el logout
        /*http.logout()
                .permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");*/

        // Configura la opcion recuerdame de la sesion
        http.rememberMe()
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(60); //1209600

        //super.configure(http);
    }



    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        //return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl  jdbcTokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        jdbcTokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return jdbcTokenRepositoryImpl;
    }

    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler () {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        authenticationSuccessHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("targetUrl");
        return authenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }
}
```

**ResourceServerConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@Order(2)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourceServerConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources
            .resourceId("recursoUno");
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        log.info("Configurando http security oauth");

        // Indica los recursos a proteger
        http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1.0/secure").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1.0/**").authenticated();

        // Configurar el estado de la sesion oauth como stateless
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Habilitar csrf para oauth
        /*http.csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize"))
                .disable();*/


        /*http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1.0/secure").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/v1.0/**").permitAll();*/

        // Configura el logout
        /*http.logout()
                .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout");*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente logré hacer funcionar la seguridad basica http junto con la seguridad oauth que necesito para la aplicacion android. No fue necesario el uso de la anotacion @Order. Gracias a la ayuda publicada en este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234159/using-websecurityconfigureradapter-with-spring-oauth2-and-user-info-uri) pude obtener la respuesta. Aqui el codigo.

**WebSecurityConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        log.info("Configurando http security web");

        http.httpBasic();

        // Indica los recursos a proteger
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/home", "/about").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/roles/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/cuenta/**").access("hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')");



        // Administra la sesion
        http.sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/invalid-session.html")
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);

        // Configura el login
        http.formLogin()
                .successHandler(savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login_check")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password");

        // Configura el logout
        http.logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout");

        // Configura la opcion recuerdame de la sesion
        http.rememberMe()
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(60); //1209600

        //super.configure(http);
    }

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        //return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl  jdbcTokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        jdbcTokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return jdbcTokenRepositoryImpl;
    }

    @Bean
    public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler () {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        authenticationSuccessHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("targetUrl");
        return authenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }
}
```

**ResourceServer.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResourceServerConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources
            .resourceId("recursoUno");
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        log.info("Configurando http security oauth");

        /* Esta fue la modificacion que se le hizo para que funcione */
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();

        /* Se cambió esta parte que no funcionaba bien
        http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1.0/secure").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/api/v1.0/**").authenticated();
        */

        // Configurar el estado de la sesion oauth como stateless
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Habilitar csrf para oauth
        /*http.csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize"))
                .disable();*/


        /*http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1.0/secure").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/v1.0/**").permitAll();*/

        // Configura el logout
        /*http.logout()
                .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout");*/
    }
}
```